# How to have multiple 'and' logical operators and an 'or' logical operator

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

It is slightly hard to explain but I want to do something that looks like this:

```
if(a === 4 && b === true && c === "words" || "numbersandwords")DoSomething();
```

but it ends running without it matching the first operators. I want to know how to have the last operator except 2 different inputs while still making sure the other criteria are met before running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use parentheses, e.g.:

```
if(a == 4 && b == true && (c == "words" || c == "numbersandwords")) { DoSomething(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a few brackets to separate your `or` parts and the `and` parts, and add the `c ===` before the last string. Without that equality part at the end, the 'numbersandwords' string always equates to true.

```
if(a === 4 && b === true && (c === "words" || c === "numbersandwords")){
  DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, like other languages, every operator (like `&&` and `||`) has a [*precendence*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) that determines the order in which it's evaluated. `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so it's evaluated first. Therefore, every term on the left is `and`ed together. Even if they are all false, however, the overall result is true because it's `or`ed with `"numbersandwords"`, which evaluates to true (as does [everything except 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)). The first thing you need to do is actually compare something (presumably `c`) to it. Then you can change the order of evaluation using parentheses, which has higher precedence than anything else:

```
if(a === 4 && b === true && (c === "words" || c === "numbersandwords")) DoSomething();
```

Alternatively, you can break the test up into several `if` statements if you may want to eventually do something slightly different based on the value of `c` (or it just better expresses your intent):

```
if(a === 4 && b === true)
{
    if(c === "words" || c === "numbersandwords")
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```